# How can I fix "Unable to add reference "TkxRFTag.tlb" error add a reference to Teklynx's Codesoft 9 in a VS project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, activex, com-interop

I am working with *Teklynx's Codesoft 9* using their automation controls. Codesoft is a label generation and printing program. I've used its sister product LabelView in the past to automate label printing, but as of LabelView 9 they dropped their automation servers.

You have to add two references: *LabelManager2* and *TkxRFTAG*. *LabelManager2* hides in the COM list as *TK Labeling ActiveX 6.0* and installed just fine. The reference to the the other has the same name *TkxRFTAG* as the library.

When I selected it I received this error including the double back slashes.

```
"Unable to add reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Teklynx\CODESOFT 9\\TkxRFTag.tlb"
```

I've had the same problem on several machines. How do you register the type library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was something odd with the backslashes, but the key was the registering the library manually.
To do that required the type library registration utility in the .Net folder.

```
C:\Users\Rich>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program
Files (x86)\Teklynx\CODESOFT 9\TkxRFTag.tlb"
Registration of TkxRFTAG.tlb successful.
```

Afterwards I had two *TkxRFTAG* entries the new one was 2.0 and it added easily to the project reference list. I don't know why there were two of them, I only installed *Codesoft* right before working with it and it was a new PC. The automation objects are installed with the base software.

Comment: I am trying to register the same TkxRFTAG.tlb file so it can be used with VS2010. I have followed your answer above and it says it has been registered successfully, but when I go to add COM reference to my project, I still just see the old version of the TkxRFTAG type library (V1.0). Any ideas why it would not be added? I am using Codesoft Basic 9.

Comment: @user1948635 - Short comment: You might try uninstalling both tlbs and then adding one back in.

Longer comments: The ActiveX controls are still under documented by Teklynx. I’ve been using Niceware NiceLabel on subsequent projects because of the issues I’ve had.

I’m not aware of a Codesoft 9 Basic, just Codesoft 9 Pro and Enterprise. Is it a European release? 
You may be talking about the ActiveX Basic. I was using ActiveX version 2 in the text above.
You can find samples on the Teklynx site.
    http://www.teklynx.com/en/resource-center/downloads/software-updates/codesoft

Comment: @user1948635 The option for regtlibv12.exe to unistall a typeLib is -U